# print response body instead of header

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

My current code prints the header information, but I want the body response. I'm trying to obtain a token to use for another request.

```
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!)
        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            print(httpResponse!)
        }})
    dataTask.resume()
```

Answer (score 1):

The content of the response is in the `data` variable of the completion block of `dataTask(with: request)`.